# equal distance between multiple circles

Tags: geometry

So my friend asked me this random maths question - heres the scenario - an alien fleet fires 6 billion bombs onto a perfectly sphircal flat planet that has a surface area 5 trillion. each bomb has a radius of 5. if all bombs fall the exact same distance apart what is the distance between each blast.

i worked it out by getting total are of explosion (6 X 78.5) = 471(X10^9)
5000 - 471 = 4529(X10^9)
4529(X10^9) / 6(X10^9) = 754.833M

now im 90% sure that im wrong because what i found is the area left not touched by explosion per bomb not the distance between said circles

Comment: I don't understand your workings. First of all, please use MathJax to typeset the equation correctly. Please don't use "X" for multiplication. For example, in the very beginning, what is this $78.5$ that you're multiplying with?

Comment: And what is a "spherical flat planet"? Is it the same as just "spherical"?

Comment: So I'm guessing you calculated that the area covered by one bomb is
$$
\pi r^2 = \pi \times 5^2 \approx 78.53
$$
And then you multiplied this by six billion. That's the total area covered by the bombs. And then what?

Comment: i deducted that from the total area of of the sphere which gave me the 4529, also sorry new to the forum dont know how to use MathJax

Comment: 2r + X = Y where X is the distance between circles and Y is the distance between center points, the diagonal wont be the same as vertical or horizontal so i tried using pytagaros to figure it out but got no where cos i dont have actual points to plot them on a graph

Comment: If you connect the centers of 4 circles, you'll have a square with a bomb at each corner. How many squares will this be and what is the length of the side of the square?

Comment: if we put it into small numbers its 6 circles on a sphere with surface area of 5000. Area of circle remains the same. so thats 2 squares with a side = Y

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Nothing suits a Black Friday better than contemplating destruction at the planetary level!

First, let's define *coverage ratio* $P$ as the fraction of the planetary surface area $A_s$ covered by the $N$ circular blasts of radius $r$, each having area $A_\circ$:

$$\bbox{A_\circ = \pi r^2} , \quad \bbox{P = \frac{A_s}{N A_\circ} = \frac{A_s}{N \pi r^2}}$$

In general, the best packing for spheres (or circular disks like here) is [hexagonal close packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_close_packing):
[image: Hexagonal close packing illustration]
If you look at the blue illustration on the right, you'll see that an [equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle) with edge length $a = r + d + r$ covers one half of a blast disk.  The area of an equilateral triangle with edge length $a$ is
$$\bbox{A_\triangle = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} a^2 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left(2 r + d\right)^2}$$
This triangle represents the hexagonal close packing pattern of the planetary bombardment, if their coverage ratios $P$ are the same:
$$\bbox{\frac{A_s}{N A_\circ} = P = \frac{A_\triangle}{\frac{1}{2} A_\circ}}$$
i.e.
$$\bbox{\frac{A_s}{N \pi r^2} = \frac{ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left(2 r + d\right)^2 }{\frac{1}{2} \pi r^2 }}$$
If we solve this for $d$, we get
$$\bbox{d = \sqrt{\frac{2 A_s}{\sqrt{3} N}} - 2 r \approx 1.07457 \sqrt{\frac{A_s}{N}} - 2 r}$$

In OP's particular case, $A_s = 5,000,000,000,000$ (assuming short trillion), $r = 5$, $N = 6,000,000,000$ (assuming short billion). Then,
$$\bbox[#ffffef, 1em]{d \approx 21}$$

---

In the illustration, the green middle figure is intended as a reminder that if complete coverage is required, $d$ must be negative. Because each angle in an equilateral triangle is $60\text{°}$, for full coverage we need
$$\bbox{2 r + d = 2 r \cos(30\text{°})}$$
i.e.
$$\bbox{d = r \left ( \sqrt{3} - 2 \right ) \approx -0.267949 r}$$
This means that to get a full coverage, i.e. every point on the surface within at least one blast radius $r$, you need $N$ bombs:
$$\bbox{N = \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{A_s}{r^2} \approx 0.3849 \frac{A_s}{r^2}}$$
In OP's case, that is about 76,980,000,000 bombs, or under 77 billion bombs; less than 13 times the suggested number of bombs, to utterly cover the planetary surface with glorious, wondrous hellfire!

Apologies, but I must now cut my contemplations short:  The nice men have come to take me back to my padded room.

Comment: (Yes, I am joking.)